# Creating a song genre map in Java

Tags: java, maps

I seem to be having a bit of difficulty in understanding how to create a map that holds a list of genres containing songs. I'm basically just hard coding in the songs and genres for now, as this will become program that later allows a user to ask for a genre and have the songs displayed.

My code so far:

```
public class Song {

  private String artist;
  private String title;
  private String fileExtension;
  private String fileName;
  private int duration; //defaults to seconds.


  public String getArtist(){
    return artist;
}
  public String getTitle(){
      return title;
  }

  public String getFileExtension(){
      return fileExtension;
  }

  public String getFileName(){
      return fileName;
  }

  public int getDuration(){
      return duration;
  }


 }
```

///////////////////////This is where I need help figuring out how to put in genres containing songs.

```
public class Genre {
    //create a selection of songs organized by a genre by using a map.
            Map<String,List<Song>> genres = new HashMap();
```

}

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: You might want to add specifically what it is you are stuck on. It seems like you want us to do it for you, but I'm sure that's not the case so please elabourate on the question.

Comment: Are you asking how to put things into the `Map` you created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible class structure.  The Map of songs could just be a List of songs if you do not have a unique identifier per song.

```
public class Song {
  // what you have here is fine, but what about some sort of id?
  // assuming the song title is the unique id for now
}

public class Genre {
  private String name;
  private Map<String, Song> songs; // where string is song title

  public Genre(String n, Map<String, Song> s) {
    name = n;
    songs = s;
  }
}

public class GenreBank {
  private Map<String, Genre> genres; // where string is genre name

  public GenreBank() {

     // If you did not understand how to physically build the maps, see here
     Map<String, Song> songList1 = new HashMap<String, Song>();
     songList1.put("title1", new Song(...));
     songList1.put("title2", new Song(...));

     Map<String, Song> songList2 = new HashMap<String, Song>();
     songList2.put("title3", new Song(...));
     songList2.put("title4", new Song(...));         

     genres = new HashMap<String, Genre>();
     genres.put("genre1", new Genre("genre1", songList1));
     genres.put("genre2", new Genre("genre2", songList2));
  }

  public Song getGenre(String genre) {
     return genres.get(genre);
  }

  public Song getSong(String title) {
    for (Genre g : genres.values()) {
      Song s = g.getSongs().get(title);
      if (s != null) { return s; }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public Song getSong(String genre, String title) {
     Genre g = genres.get(genre);
     if (g != null) {
        return g.getSongs().get(title);
     }
     return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think his original implementation of a `List<Song>` is better suited to the idea of genres. With this implementation, you have to know the title of the song and its genre to retrieve it, when you should be able to just get the `Song` from its title

Comment: I'll just add another method to support that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would organize it. Create a `Genre` class with an appropriate name field and a `List` of `Songs`.

Then add static modifiers to get a `List` of all current `Genres`

```
public class Genre {

    private String name;
    private List<Song> songs;

    public Genre(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        songs = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }   
    public List<Song> getSongs() {
        return songs;
    }

    private static List<Genre> genres = new ArrayList<>();

    public static List<Song> getSongs(String genreName) {
        for (Genre genre : genres) {
            if (genre.getName().equals(genreName)) {
                return genre.getSongs();
            }
        }
        return new ArrayList(); //Return empty list if no songs found for a given name
    }

}
```

From here you can create additional static methods to add songs to a `Genre`, create and register a new `Genre`, and much more.

For grins, here's an implementation to add a `Song` to a `Genre` by its name, and lazily create that `Genre` if it doesn't exist:

```
public static void addSong(Song song, String genreName) {
    for (Genre genre : genres) {
        if (genre.getName().equals(genreName)) {
            genre.getSongs().add(song);
            return;
        }
    }
    //If no genre was found (return would have been called), create a new one
    Genre genre = new Genre(genreName);
    genre.getSongs().add(song);
    genres.add(genre);

}
```